# Drawing angle bisectors in a triangle

Tags: graphics, functions, regions, geometry, trigonometry

In triangle $\triangle ABC$, the angle $\angle BAC$ is equal to $60°$, $|AB|=2$, $|BC|=\sqrt 6$, and $AD$ bisects the angle $\angle BAC$ and $BC$ at point $D$.

How can I find the length of the angle bisector $AD$ and draw it?

I have drawn the triangle using the following code:

```
sol = First@
   Solve[{c == 2, a == Sqrt[6], 
     6 == b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c Cos[60 Degree], {a, b, c} > 0}, {a, b, c}];
{A1, B1, C1} = First@SSSTriangle[a, b, c] /. sol;
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], A1, {2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], B1, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], C1, {2, -1}]};
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], SSSTriangle[a, b, c] /. sol, 
  labels}]
```

Comment: Search the documentation: `Names["*" <> # <> "*"] & /@ {"Triangle", "Bisect"}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Actually, if one searches "angle bisector", `TriangleConstruct` will be 2nd entry: https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=angle%20bisector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tri = SSSTriangle[a, b, c] /. sol;
```

You can use [`TriangleConstruct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangleConstruct.html) and extract the property `"AngleBisectingCevian"`

```
angleBisectingCevian = TriangleConstruct[tri, {"AngleBisectingCevian", 1}];

N @ ArcLength @ angleBisectingCevian
```

> ```
> 2.
> ```

```
D1 = angleBisectingCevian[[1, 2]];

Graphics[{labels, FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], tri, Dashed, 
  angleBisectingCevian, Red, PointSize@Large, Point@D1, 
  Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], D1, {-2, 0}]}]
```

[image]

```
abc = TriangleConstruct[tri, {"AngleBisectingCevian", All}];

Graphics[{labels, FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], tri, 
  Dashed, abc,
  Red, PointSize @ Large, 
  MapThread[{Point @ #2, 
      Text[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, #3]} &]@
   {{a, b, c}, abc[[All, 1, 2]], {{-2, -1}, {2, -1}, {0, 1}}}}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"
> ```

Comment: TriangleConstruct[tri, {"AngleBisectingCevian", 1}]  Does this function require networking to be used?

Comment: it is a documented system function available in versions 12.0+.

Comment: {"AngleBisectingCevian", 1}What is the meaning of parameter 1? Is it the first vertex A representing a triangle?

Comment: right; `{"AngleBisectingCevian",p}` is _cevian bisecting the interior angle at the vertex p_.

Comment: @csn899 And this is mentioned in **Details** section of document of `TriangleConstruct`, please read the document carefully.

Answer (score 4):

To appreciate and compare the time saved by using `Triangleconstruct`, here is an alternative answer.

**Without `TriangleConstruct`:**

One can use `AngleBisector`.

```
tri = Triangle[{A1, B1, C1}];
bisector = AngleBisector[{B1, A1, C1}]; (* Returns InfiniteLine *)
ptD = RegionIntersection[Line[{B1, C1}], bisector][[-1, -1]];
bseg = Line[{A1, ptD}] (* bisector line segment *)
blen = RegionMeasure[bseg]

Graphics[{
  {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black]
   , tri, labels}
  , {Dashed, Red, bseg}
  , {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point@ptD}
  , {Darker@Green, Thick, Dashed
   , Circle[A1, blen
    , {-π/30, π/6 + π/5}]
   }
  , {Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15]
    , ptD, {-2, -2}]}
  , {Text[Style[Rotate[NumberForm[blen, {2, 2}]
      , PlanarAngle[{B1, A1, ptD}]]
     , 14]
    , Midpoint[bseg], {0.5, -1}]
   }
  }
 ]
```

---

Or extract the incenter using `TriangleConstruct` as the three bisectors pass through this point. (see below for a method without using `Triangleconstruct`)

```
tri = Triangle[{A1, B1, C1}];
incenter = TriangleConstruct[tri, "Incenter"][[-1]];
ptD = RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[{A1, incenter}], 
    Line[{B1, C1}]][[-1, -1]];
bseg = Line[{A1, ptD}]; (* bisector line segment *)
blen = RegionMeasure[bseg];

Graphics[{
  {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], tri, labels}
  , {Black, PointSize@Large, Point@incenter}
  , {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point@ptD}
  , {Thin, Black, InfiniteLine[{A1, incenter}]}
  , {Dashed, Gray, InfiniteLine[{B1, incenter}]}
  , {Dashed, Gray, InfiniteLine[{C1, incenter}]}
  , {Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15]
    , ptD, {-2, -2}]}
  , {Text[Style[Rotate[NumberForm[blen, {2, 2}]
      , PlanarAngle[{B1, A1, ptD}]]
     , 14]
    , Midpoint[bseg], {0.5, -1}]
   }
  }
 ]
```

[image]

---

To calculate the incenter without `TriangleConstruct`.

```
sideab = RegionMeasure[Line[{A1, B1}]]
sidebc = RegionMeasure[Line[{B1, C1}]]
sideac = RegionMeasure[Line[{A1, C1}]]

ic = {sideab, sidebc, sideac} . {C1, A1, B1}/
 Total@{sideab, sidebc, sideac}
```

> {1.14128, 0.658919}

```
ic == incenter
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[A1, B1, C1, D1, sol,labels];
c = 2;
A1 = {0, 0};
B1 = {c, 0};
C1 = {x, y};
sol = Solve[{EuclideanDistance[B1, C1] == Sqrt[6], 
     PlanarAngle[{B1, A1, C1}] == π/3}, PositiveReals][[1]];
C1 = {x, y} /. sol // FullSimplify;
b = EuclideanDistance[A1, C1] // FullSimplify;
D1 = b/(b + c)*B1 + c/(b + c)*C1 // FullSimplify;
(* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem *)
```

```
EuclideanDistance[A1, D1]
```

> `2`

```
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], A1, {2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], B1, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], C1, {2, -1}], 
   Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], D1, {-2, -1}]};
Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Triangle[{A1, B1, C1}], Red, 
   Line[{A1, D1}]}, labels}]
```

[image]

Comment: Using the properties of angular bisectors to find the coordinates of intersection points